# Getting trouble dealing with links having differntly paginated structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape the titles of different items located at the right sided area right next to the map of its landing page. There are two links I've used within my script: one has pagination and the other don't have.

When I execute my script, it first check for the pagination links. If it finds one then it passes the links to `get_paginated_info()` function to print result there. However, if it fails to find pagination links then it passes the soup object to `get_info()` function and prints the result there. The script at this moment works just exactly the way I described.

***How can I make my script print the result within `get_info()` function only whether the link has pagination or not complying with the logic I've already tried to apply as I wish to kick out `get_paginated_info()` function from my script?***

This my attempt so far:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urls = (
    'https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/maine/all',
    'https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/rhode-island/all',
)

def get_names(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    items = soup.select_one(".pagination a.next_page")
    if items:
        npagelink = items.find_previous_sibling().get("href").split("/")[-1]
        return [get_paginated_info(link + "/page/{}".format(page)) for page  in range(1,int(npagelink)+1)]

    else:
        return [get_info(soup)]

def get_info(soup):
    print("================links without pagination==============")
    for items in soup.select("td[class='table-row-price']"):
        item = items.select_one("h2 a").text
        print(item)

def get_paginated_info(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    print("================links with pagination==============")
    for content in sauce.select("td[class='table-row-price']"):
        title = content.select_one("h2 a").text
        print(title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        get_names(url)
```

Any better design capable of dealing with different liks will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly have changed the logic. So now both in cases when Pagination is there and when there is no Pagination script will call `get_names`. But in second case in `for` loop only one iteration will be executed

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urls = (
    'https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/maine/all',
    'https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/rhode-island/all',
)

def get_names(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    items = soup.select_one(".pagination a.next_page")
    try:
        npagelink = items.find_previous_sibling().get("href").split("/")[-1]
    except AttributeError:
        npagelink = 1
    return [get_info(link + "/page/{}".format(page)) for page in range(1, int(npagelink) + 1)]


def get_info(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for content in sauce.select("td[class='table-row-price']"):
        title = content.select_one("h2 a").text
        print(title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        get_names(url)
```

Please **double-check** the output to be sure that everything works as expected

Comment: This is more elegant and cocise. At a glance, it seems all the result are coming through. Appreciate your awesome help @sir Andersson.