# Can't get all links of defferent items

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script to harvest the links of different products from a webpage. My intention is to scrape the links only when the products have `Ajouter au panier` sign, meaning `Add to Basket`. The html structures are very straightforward and easy to play with but the logic to get the desired links appears to be tricky. I've used three different links to show the variation.

Few urls lead to the desired products but still there are catalogues (if i make use of their links) which produces some more products. Check out the image links to see for yourself. I've drawn circles around the catalogues in the first image which can still produces the desired products whereas in that page few desired products are already there.

[check out the variation](https://pasteboard.co/HTbjXLk.jpg)

[another one: only catalogues](https://pasteboard.co/HTblvE5.jpg)

This is the script I've written:

```
import requests 
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = (
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/aspirateurs-de-mucosite.html",
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/literie.html",
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/vetement.html"
    )

def get_links(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".browseCategoryName a"):
        ilink = urljoin(link,item.get("href"))
        print(ilink)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        get_links(url)
```

How can I get all the products links having `Ajouter au panier` signs using those urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select Product links from both initial page and (if there are no products on initial page) from Category page, try

```
import requests 
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

domain = "https://www.directmedical.fr/"
urls = (
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/aspirateurs-de-mucosite.html",
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/literie.html",
    "https://www.directmedical.fr/categorie/vetement.html"
    )

def get_links(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    products = soup.select(".browseElements td > a")
    if products:
        for item in products:
            ilink = urljoin(link, item.get("href"))
            print(ilink)
    else:
        categories = [urljoin(domain, item.get("href")) for item in soup.select(".browseChildsCategorys td > a")]
        for category in categories:
            c = requests.get(category)
            c_soup = BeautifulSoup(c.text, "lxml")
            for item in c_soup.select(".browseElements td > a"):
                c_link = urljoin(domain, item.get("href"))
                print(c_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        get_links(url)
```

Comment: Best solution in my coding experience @sir Andersson. One upvote is certainly not enough for this solution. One thing for my understanding sir: whether the `products` variable contain anything or not the `else` block will always activate, ain't it? Thanks.

Comment: @asmitu `if products` checks whether the list of products is not empty. Only if the list is empty then `else` block will be executed

Comment: I executed your script again to recheck whether all the links are being scraped. And yes they are. So, I should not worry about this `browseChildsCategorys` class as long as there are `browseElements` class present, right? I attempted to grab both of then when I created this post. Looks like `browseChildsCategorys` are there to create confusion beause without them I can get their content (using first link) as well.

Comment: @asmitu , as I understand if there are `browseElements` on page then `browseChildsCategorys` just contains exactly the same links as `browseElements`. You can of course remove `if`/`else` and just scrape links from both Products and Category pages, add them to list and then apply `set()` to remove duplicates...

Comment: I would be very glad if you check out ***[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907982/getting-trouble-dealing-with-links-having-differntly-paginated-structure)*** @sir Andersson. I've just edited the post to make it clearer. Thanks.